# Node.js doesnt update its value after data request on Couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cradle

i just create a gallery page in Node.js using help from Express and Cradle.io to communicate with CouchDB using this code below (images are saved in CouchDB attachment):

```
app.get("/album/:id", function(req, res){
var id  = req.params.id;
db.get(id, function(err, album){
    console.log(album);
    res.send(album);
})
```

and after some careful research i found out that although i just updated my database, and reload the page to resend /GET "album/:id" form browser, the Node server doesn't seem to update the "album" variable there. so what i miss here ?

Comment: 1. where is the update code?
2. why `console.log` and not `res.send(album)`?

Comment: i use res.send(album) in my actual code, here i use console.log(album) for simplification only. the problem is whenever /album/:id id called the value of "album" variable doesn't change.

Comment: then it's possible the update code is not working. can you share it?

Comment: doing just like the code above, and variable 'album' won't updates although, in CouchDB I just updated its value using FUTON and i have been check its value from FUTON, and its value are correct. It's seems that db.get() function just keep values from previous call. If i restarted my Node server, than album's value will be updated to its latest value.